# Vertical concatenation of many vectors Mata/Stata

Tags: vector, concatenation, stata

I am working with Mata (Stata) trying to append (vertically concatenate) many vectors.
I would like to do something like

```
mat C = A\B
```

but since I have about 300 column vectors to append in a unique column vector, I would like to know if there is a command to do it (since it is quite difficult to type

```
mat C = c1\c2\c3...
```

300 times).

Answer (score 3):

The code you cite is Stata's matrix language, which is **not** Mata.

How did you get these vectors in the first place? Are they named systematically?

There is a likely to be an easy answer depending on the details.

For example, in Stata you can go with column vectors `c1` ... `c300`

```
mat C = c1 
forval j = 2/300 {
    mat C = C \ c`j'
}
```

although the `matsize` limit may mean you are better off handling such a column vector as a Stata variable or in Mata.

EDIT: To produce a matrix in Stata from those columns, use `,` not `\`.

Comment: First of all,thank you for your replay. The vectors are the columns of a matrix (n*n, about 300*300) so they are named systematically from c1 to c300. The problem with the loop you showed me is, as you already pointed out, the matsize. Indeed "appending" all the vectors I will have a coulmn vector of 90000 rows whihch, from what I know, is not manageable in stata. I thought that passing through Mata I could manage, save, and store it as a stata database, but I don't know how to obtain the equivalent result of your loop in Mata. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How you did get those vectors into or in Stata? If you want one vector, why not use `svmat` and then reshape to a single `Stata` variable? See also my comment on @Aspen Chen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code adopts Nick's logic but uses the Mata language.

```
mat c=(1,4,7,10\2,5,8,11\3,6,9,12) // 3 x 4 matrix
mat list c

mata
c=st_matrix("c")          // Stata matrix into Mata matrix
x=c[.,1]
for (i=2; i<5;i++)  {
x=x\c[.,i]
}
st_matrix("newC",x)       // Mata matrix into Stata matrix
end

mat list newC
```

Comment: It's true that you can read a Stata matrix into Mata, reshape it to a column vector and then push it back. In fact you could do that in one line as `st_matrix("c", colshape(st_matrix("c"), 1))`. But this misses the OP's comment that Stata's `matsize` limit rules this out in the practical case being considered.

Comment: However, your answer underlines that a Stata matrix can be imported into Mata and changed to a column vector and manipulated within Mata.

Comment: @Nick Cox You're right. This would only have worked if the subsequent manipulation was to be done in Mata. I think we need to know what the OP intends to do with this concatenated vector/variable. I'd imagine another way to get around the limit is to loop through all 300 matrix columns, one at a time.

Comment: I agree with your analysis.

Comment: Dear all,
the example proposed by Aspen Chen with the (3x4) matrix is exactly what I would like to obtain from my data.
I tried the loop in Mata proposed by Aspen Chen and works perfectly. And also the strategy with st_matrix("c", colshape(st_matrix("c"), 1)).
As you already pointed out,the problem arises when I tried to store it as a stata dataset using xsvmat(since I need it for further manipulation as regressions etc.),
because I dobtain the error
obs must be between 0 and 5242876
r(198);
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3782695 As Nick already pointed out, my solution doesn't work for a 300x300 matrix because of `matsize`. That is, unless the subsequent manipulation is solely conducted in Mata. In that case, more context on what you intent to do is needed before we can offer suggestions.

Comment: As for the error, it shouldn't occur if the number of observations is only 90,000. Show us the exact code that led to the error. You can even use a fake data with something like `mat c=J(300,300,1)` to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Dear all, after this attempts I decided to change strategy and I will simply use export the 300x300 matrix in a stata dataset (with xsvmat) and then I will use the reshape command, since I decided to change the further manipulations that I have to do. Thank you. E.C.